# Hadoop configuration values cloudera

Tags: hadoop

I installed hadoop via cloudera manager using parcels.

I need to find the path of the variables where the following variables are set.

```
HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME 
MR2_CLASSPATH
HADOOP_COMMON_HOME
JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH
HADOOP_CLIENT_CONF_DIR
HADOOP_CONF_DIR 
HADOOP_HDFS_HOME
HADOOP_YARN_HOME
```

Can someone please help me with this. Where can i find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find these environment variables set under cloudera installed directory. Generally, it does install under "opt" directory, so path to configurations of hadoop cluster would be : opt > cloudera > parcels > CDH > etc, where you can search for these environment variables.